# Exclude requests by querystring from being served as static files

Tags: nginx

There is a mono fastcgi server running in the background and nginx in front. I want all css / js but two special requests handled by nginx as static files.

My nginx config looks like this

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

location / {
                  root /srv/www/vhosts/abcde.de/;
                  fastcgi_index /;
                  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          }
```

Now `/mini-profiler-includes.css?v=1.9.0.0` and `/mini-profiler-includes.js?v=1.9.0.0` should be handled by the fastcgi server and not by nginx as static files.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

An additional regex location block like this would do it.

```
location ~* mini(.*)\.(js|css)$ {
                 fastcgi_index /;
                 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
```

But the fastcgi settings are redundant then.